# GIS Web API - WFS-T Edit

Tags: openlayers-2, editing, google-maps-api, wfs-t

My organization has a asset management application using Google Maps Java API as the GIS viewer.  The application does some simple editing/querying on a kml file through html form elements.

**Instead of editing against the kml files, can the API edit/query against a WFS-T service (served by ArcGIS Server)?**

**If not, can I modify this OpenLayers WFS-T Using a GeoServer Hosted PostGIS (link below) Layerinstructions to edit against ArcGIS Server/SDE database/WFS-T?**

http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html

```
//wfs-t editable overlay
var wfs_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
//projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:26910"),
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
version: "1.1.0",
// loading data through localhost url path
url: "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs",
featureNS :  "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
maxExtent: mapextent,
// layer name
featureType: "wfst_test",
// geometry column name
geometryName: "the_geom",
schema: "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&;typename=cite:wfst_test"
})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Server has supported WFS-T [since 2009](http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/summer09articles/arcgis-server-ogc.html). Their help site has a tutorial on [publishing  WFS-T layers](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#tutorial_wfst_service.htm). You might want to check it out. There's also a paper on the ESRI developer library that shows an overview of the [OGC capabilities that you can leverage with ArcGIS Server](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit09/papers/leveraging_the_ogc_capabilities_of_arcgis_server_devconf_2009.pdf).

I suggest that you check the paper first and then dive into the tutorial once you're convinced that it's the one you want. You shouldn't have to change anything on the OpenLayers side. It's the ArcGIS Server side that you have to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if ArcGIS Server supports WFS-T. They didn't a few years ago.

But one way (if you are stuck with ArcGIS) should be to let GeoServer generate the wfs-t service from ArcGIS data.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/arcsde.html