# How can I use wms service layers to edit in openlayers?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, openlayers-2, arcgis-server, wms

I'm new to openlayers. I'd like to edit a feature layer of wms service in openlayers.

I created a wms service using ArcGIS server 10. I couldn't use the wms layers to edit using the openlayers editor. Is there any solution to set layers of the wms service (ex: layer 1 of wms service) to edit in openlayers? In other words, how can I set the wms layer to `OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar()`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Creating a simple map</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Include OpenLayers library -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.11/
OpenLayers.js"></script>

    <script
            src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.
ashx?v=6.2&mkt=en-us"></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {

            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("rcp1_map");
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

            // Add a WMS layer

            var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("test",
                    "http://.../ArcGIS/services/test/MapServer/WMSServer",
                    {
                        layers: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6',
                        transparent: "true",
                        format: 'image/png'

                    },
            {
                isBaseLayer: false
            }

            );
            var ve_shaded = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth(
                    "Shaded",
                    {type: VEMapStyle.Shaded}
            );
            var ve_aerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth(
                    "Aerial",
                    {type: VEMapStyle.Aerial}
            );
            var ve_road = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth(
                    "Road",
                    {animationEnabled: false}
            );
            var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('VectorLayer')
        map.addLayers([vector_layer,wms,ve_shaded, ve_aerial, ve_road]);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(54, 32),4)

            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(????));


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="rcp1_map" style="width: 100%;
height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK WMS is not editable in a web client and so with OpenLayers. Maybe you were thinking about the WFS-T protocol which is editable instead. Here's a [WFS Transaction Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html) with OpenLayers.

Comment: Here is a WFT-T tutorial for ArcGIS Server v10.1, http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003m3000000.

Comment: @afalciano so, I created WFS service using ArcGIS server 10 but i couldn't use it in openlayers . In fact i couldn't set some parameters such as featureNS . in detail  i created a WFS from MXD. In my MXD I have a shapefile named "turkey_wgs". every samples in the internet uses geoservernot arcgis server . thanks for advance

Comment: Note that WFS-T is different from a WFS. Have you followed the tutorial provided by @artwork21 ? See also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20814/gis-web-api-wfs-t-edit

Comment: then i should change the arcgis version from 10 to 10.1

Comment: No, you need to change the tutorial version from 10.1 to 10: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Tutorial_Publishing_a_WFS_T_service/00530000000r000000/